# how to make columns editable in react table 7

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I want editable cells in a specific column in my table. There are examples for the older version of react table but, how can i do the same in version 7. Any example will suffice, simple code will do just great.

I don't know how to do it as i am new to this stuff.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is a bit late... Using the example from [official documentation](https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/examples/editable-data), you can add a conditional check for the columns that need to be editable. Here is my example ensuring that all columns BUT the first is editable or rendering an input tag:

```
// Check to make sure not all columns are editable
if (id !== "col1") {
    return <input value={value} onChange={onChange} onBlur={onBlur} />;
}
return value;
```

In this case my first column has an **id** of **col1**. My data array looks like this:

```
const data = [
    {
        col1: 'Name',
        col2: 'James'
    },
    {
        col1: 'Surname',
        col2: 'Bond'
    },
]
```

Here is all my code using the example from the [documentation](https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/examples/editable-data):

```
import { useState, useMemo, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Table, TableBody, TableCell, TableContainer, TableHead, TableRow, Box, Typography } from '@mui/material';
import { useTable } from 'react-table';

// Some external data
const data = [
    {
        col1: 'Name',
        col2: 'James',
    },
    {
        col1: 'Surname',
        col2: 'Bond',
    },
];

function DetailsTable () {
    const [dataRows, setData] = useState(data);
    const [skipPageReset, setSkipPageReset] = useState(false);

    const columns = useMemo(() => [
        {
            Header: 'Lables',
            accessor: 'col1'
        },
        {
            Header: 'Details',
            accessor: 'col2'
        },
    ], []);

    // Editable cell code
    const updateMyData = (rowIndex, columnId, value) => {
        // We also turn on the flag to not reset the page
        setSkipPageReset(true);
        setData(old =>
            old.map((row, index) => {
                if (index === rowIndex) {
                    return {
                        ...old[rowIndex],
                        [columnId]: value,
                    };
                }
                return row;
            })
        );
    };

    // Create an editable cell renderer
    const EditableCell = ({
        value: initialValue,
        row: { index },
        column: { id },
        updateMyData, // This is a custom function that we supplied to our table instance
    }) => {
        // We need to keep and update the state of the cell normally
        const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);


        const onChange = e => {
            setValue(e.target.value);
        };

        // We'll only update the external data when the input is blurred
        const onBlur = () => {
            updateMyData(index, id, value);
        };

        // If the initialValue is changed external, sync it up with our state
        useEffect(() => {
            setValue(initialValue);
        }, [initialValue]);

        // Check to make sure not all columns are editable
        if (id !== "col1") {
            return <input value={value} onChange={onChange} onBlur={onBlur} />;
        }
        return value;
    };

    // Set our editable cell renderer as the default Cell renderer
    const defaultColumn = {
        Cell: EditableCell,
    };


    useEffect(() => {
        setSkipPageReset(false);
        console.log(dataRows);
    }, [dataRows]);

    const tableInstance = useTable({ columns, data, defaultColumn, autoResetPage: !skipPageReset, updateMyData });
    const {
        getTableProps,
        getTableBodyProps,
        headerGroups,
        rows,
        prepareRow,
    } = tableInstance;

    return (
        <Box sx={{
            marginBottom: 10,
            height: 600,
            width: '100%'
        }}>
            <Typography variant="h3" component="h3">DetailsForm Title</Typography>
            <TableContainer>
                <Table stickyHeader {...getTableProps()}>
                    <TableHead>
                        {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
                            <TableRow {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
                                {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
                                    <TableCell {...column.getHeaderProps()}>
                                        {column.render('Header')}
                                    </TableCell>
                                ))}
                            </TableRow>
                        ))}
                    </TableHead>
                    <TableBody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
                        {rows.map((row, i) => {
                            prepareRow(row);
                            return (
                                <TableRow {...row.getRowProps()}>
                                    {row.cells.map(cell => {
                                        return (
                                            <TableCell {...cell.getCellProps()}>
                                                {cell.render('Cell')}
                                            </TableCell>
                                        );
                                    })}
                                </TableRow>
                            );
                        })}
                    </TableBody>
                </Table>
            </TableContainer>
        </Box>
    );
}

export default DetailsTable;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find a complete example in the attached url.

https://react-table.js.org/examples/simple#editable-data

Comment: HI Rehan thanks it is a good example. But i only want one column editable maybe two. In this example all the columns are editable. How can I set which columns to edit.

Comment: You can create only one custom component for Editable cell and can use it in the table.  For now each and every `Cell` is an `EditableCell`. But if you want any specific then you can make that specific column editable.

Comment: i was able to do that by using a check in the EditableCell function in which i check the column i want to edit. But if you may, can you provide an example code  for setting a custom component because that would be great.